# Traverse simple javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'm having a mental block. How may I access the data inside this javascript object that's returned from an ajax function?

I was thinking something like this would work:

```
data[0].id would return 1 
data[1].category.description would return "MEN"
```

Help would be appreciated!

```
"[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "description" : "PANTS",
  "price" : 10.99,
  "category" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "MEN"
  },
  "customerType" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "COUNTER"
  }
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "description" : "SHIRT",
  "price" : 4.99,
  "category" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "MEN"
  },
  "customerType" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "type" : "COUNTER"
  }
} ]"
```

Comment: It looks like you're pasting the raw string, which I would assume you haven't parsed into an object.

Comment: Please delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work, just loop over it

```
dataLength=data.length;
for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
    var dataID = data[i].id;
    var dataCatagory = data[i].category.description;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response, I was just posting my own response as you typed yours. Duh.. Just a dumb brain freeze

Comment: I'll accept your post in 7 minutes LOL Thanks again

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to all of us :P

Comment: per comment above by zzzzBov I wasn't parsing it first, then I could traverse it as normal. Thought Id add that to the comment in case someone else had a brainfreeze like me. Just do JSON.parse(data) then use a loop or whatever and it'll work as any other normal javascript object

Answer (score 0):

ah jeez.. I figured out a simple way to get the data out. I can do something like this:

```
currentrow = data[i];
id = currentrow.id;
```

Or use id or the other values as such. Nevermind my posting, I'm an idiot sometimes